# Center an inline list in div example not working

Tags: html, css

I am creating a liquid layout example as shown below using the exact html example shown in the book *HTML and CSS by Jon Duckett*-

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #665544;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 400px;
}

#content {
  overflow: auto;
}

#nav,
#feature,
#footer {
  margin: 1%;
}

.column1,
.column2,
.column3 {
  width: 31.3%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}

.column3 {
  margin-right: 0%;
  /* No effect anyway as float is left */
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#nav,
#footer {
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}

#feature,
.article {
  height: 10em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Liquid Layout</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li id="home"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="feature">
      <p>Feature</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article column1">
      <p>Column One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article column2">
      <p>Column Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article column3">
      <p>Column Three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>&copy; Copyright 2011</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When viewed in full screen, the `ul` list isn't fully in the centre of the div. 
I thought, to centre the div, I should do two things

1. Define a width less than the container.
2. Set the margin to `0 auto`

So, I set the `ul` element width to 70% and margin to `0 auto`. 
The result in the snippet below however produces a strange result.

```css
  * {
   font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
   color: #665544;
   text-align: center;
  }
  
  body {
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   min-width: 400px;
  }
  
  #content {
   overflow: auto;
  }
  #nav, #feature, #footer {
   margin: 1%;
  }
  .column1, .column2, .column3 {
   width: 31.3%;
   float: left;
   margin: 1%;
  }
  .column3 {
   margin-right: 0%;
   /* No effect anyway as float is left */
  }
  ul {
   width: 70%;
   margin: auto;
  }
  li {
   display: inline;
   padding: 0.5em;
  }
  #nav, #footer {
   background-color: #efefef;
   padding: 0.5em 0;
  }
  #feature, .article {
   height: 10em;
   margin-bottom: 1em;
   background-color: #efefef;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Liquid Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  <div id="nav">
   <ul>
    <li id="home"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
  <div id="feature">
   <p>Feature</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article column1">
   <p>Column One</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article column2">
   <p>Column Two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article column3">
   <p>Column Three</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
  <p>&copy; Copyright 2011</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All of the padding is lost, and the list is still not fully centered. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No need for width changes. Just add `padding-left: 0` to the **ul**. That should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `padding-left:0px;` to the ul. It is a style default that the web automatically provides -- to add a padding to ul elements.

Here's a screenshot from my computer. The chrome browser gives ul's the default styling below.

[image]

Comment: The padding is still there. What you lost was the vertical margin on the ul that was there before. If you inspect the element on both of the code snippets and look at the ul inside of the #nav, you'll see that the padding was actually margin from the ul.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the default padding for `ul` elements by adding this:

```
#nav > ul {
  padding: 0
}
```

Full snippet:

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #665544;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 400px;
}

#content {
  overflow: auto;
}

#nav,
#feature,
#footer {
  margin: 1%;
}
#nav > ul {
  padding: 0
}
.column1,
.column2,
.column3 {
  width: 31.3%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}

.column3 {
  margin-right: 0%;
  /* No effect anyway as float is left */
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#nav,
#footer {
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}

#feature,
.article {
  height: 10em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Liquid Layout</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li id="home"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="feature">
      <p>Feature</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article column1">
      <p>Column One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article column2">
      <p>Column Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article column3">
      <p>Column Three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>&copy; Copyright 2011</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```